# Can I get / How can I get the full user profile and roles from OpenAM after authentication?

Tags: openam, spring-saml

My project authentication use OpenAM with Spring Security and SAML extension.
It's work fine.

I implemented the **SAMLUserDetailsService** interface, get back the uid (user id) from OpenAM (**nameid-format:unspecified**).

It's ok too, but I need the user information (email, phone...) and roles from OpenAM. How can I do this from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more claims to the SAML assertion (the docs describe how to do this). Use something like Firefox SAML tracer to view the SAML assertions.

You could also query the users profile directly from OpenDJ using their uid.